# How to know if a git submodule commit is already pushed into the repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose you have a repository called super and a submodule called sub. Stand in super, I'd like to know if sub last commit is already pushed to the repository or if it's local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At super> "git status" will show you "modified: submodule/sub (new commits)" if the local sub is at a different commit point than the local super's committed submodule.

At sub> "git log origin/master..master" will show you commits from the pushed 'master' branch and local 'master' branch, if any.

Does this answer your question? If not, please clarify.

Comment: The second idea did the trick. What about if in the submodule you are in any branch and only have a commit id?

Comment: @visitor1: `git branch -r --contains HEAD` will show if any of the remote-tracking branches already contain the currently checked out commit.