# How to know if a commit is pushed in a repository?

Tags: git, git-commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: check if commit xyz in remote repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549479/git-check-if-commit-xyz-in-remote-repo)

If I have a commit hash, how can I know if it is pushed in a repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549479/git-check-if-commit-xyz-in-remote-repo

Comment: And you've already asked and received an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154935/how-to-know-if-a-git-submodule-commit-is-already-pushed-into-the-repository